# How do you get to the inner error of a SPHttpClientResponse that's not OK/200?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm trying to do some error handling in an SPFx web part, and I can't seem to get to the inner error message of a response that's not what I'm expecting.

In the following code snippet, I've deliberately added some xxx's to the `accept` header in order to get an error response.  If I log it in the console, I can see it, but if I try to get to the `message` property, it comes back `undefined`.

```
private loadMyList() {
    // baseUri is essentially this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl
    const { spClient, baseUri }: IMyComponentState = this.state;
    const uri: string = `${baseUri}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${strings.MyListName}')`;
    spClient.get(uri, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/jsonxxxx'
        }
    }).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        console.log(response.status) // with the xxx's in the header, this is 406
        console.log(response.statusText) // "Not Acceptable", also, not useful
        response.json().then(responseJSON => {
            if (response.status === 404) {
                // expected the possibility of list not found, do something else
            } else if (response.status === 200) {
                // expected the possibility of list found, responseJSON is the list object
            } else {
                // was some other error
                console.log(responseJSON);
                // responseJSON is an object with properties "code" and "message"
                // but
                console.log('message:', responseJSON.message); // undefined
                console.log('has own property', responseJSON.hasOwnProperty('message')); // false

                // but yet it clearly _does_ have a message property
            }
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        // do something with the error
    });
}
```

Here's what shows up in the console:
[image: screen shot of console]

So how do I get to that inner error message?  The `response.statusText` of "Not Acceptable" is not as useful as the message detailing that there's a problem with the `accept` header.

Comment: I don't suppose you can access `response.responseText`? If it were an unextended XMLHttpRequest object I were dealing with, that's the property I'd examine.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not there.  The `SPHttpClientResponse` class is barely an extension of the `HttpClientResponse` class, for which the documentation can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-http/httpclientresponse?view=sp-typescript-latest). `responseText` is not a property or method there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot of your console output for `responseJSON` it looks like the `message` property is buried under a property called `error`.

You should be able to read the message by accessing `responseJSON.error.message`

Comment: O. M. G. I am having a serious facepalm moment right now.  I can't believe I didn't see that.  One of those days, I guess.

Comment: Never hurts to have an extra set of eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

Go straight to the source. [Fiddle](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) the web traffic and look at the raw response from the server. Alternately you might have luck looking at the Network tab in Chrome dev tools.